# JS: Click one div, change another div value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a vote button I created that is contained within a .vote_div. 2 parts: .vote_num for the vote total, and .vote for the vote button. The page has a list of items so I need to make sure when the user clicks .vote, it changes the corresponding .vote_num + 1.

My JS function worked when the .vote actually was the total votes, but now I am seperating the two. How do I grab the right .vote_num on the .vote click?

Thanks!

```
<script>
$(".vote").click( function() {
    var votes = $(this).attr('votes');
    $.post(
        '{% url vote %}', {
            "id":this.id,
    }, function(data) {});
    this.className = "voted";
    $(this).text(parseInt(votes) + 1);
    return false;
});
</script>


   <div class="vote_div">
    <span class="vote_num" votes='{{host.num_votes}}'>{{host.num_votes}}</span>
    <span class="vote" id="{{host.user.id}}">Vote</span>
   </div>
```

**EDIT & SOLUTION:**

Got it working using $(this).parent() :

```
<script>
$(".vote").click( function() {
    var votes = $(this).parent().find('.vote_num').attr('votes');
    $.post(
        '{% url vote %}', {
            "id":this.id,
    }, function(data) {});
    this.className = "voted";
    votes = parseInt(votes) + 1;
    $(this).parent().find('.vote_num').text(votes);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var votes = $(this).parent().find('.vote_num').attr('votes');
```

It goes to the parent of the clicked `div` then looks for an element with class `vote_num` then grabs the `votes` attributes.

@James answer should work, but this should give you a little more freedom to rearrange the two divs and add other elements so long as they share the parent.

To be even more robust you could do (note the 's' on "parents")

```
var votes = $(this).parents('.vote_div').find('.vote_num').attr('votes');
```

This will allow the elements to be nested arbitrarily deep as long as they only have a single parent with a class of `vote_div'.

See: http://api.jquery.com/parent/ , http://api.jquery.com/parents/ , and http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

```
var votes = $(this).attr('votes');
```

'votes' does not belong to class 'vote', it belongs to class 'vote_num'

so the line should be

```
var votes = $(".vote_num").attr('votes');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple class with vote, maybe you should use each()

```
$(".vote").each(function () {
   var current = $(this);
   current.click = function  () {
     // the rest of your function 
   }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly, and also assuming that your `vote_num` element is always the first element in the `vote_div` element:

```
var votes = $(this).siblings().eq(0).attr("votes");
```

Put this inside your click event handler will get the `votes` attribute from the first sibling element of the clicked element.

You can make this simpler if you are sure the element in question will always be directly before the clicked element:

```
var votes = $(this).prev().attr("votes");
```

Comment: You can apply a selector to the `siblings()` there, instead of using `eq()`. Assuming that the structure is always the same and there's always only one vote_num element `siblings('.vote_num')` should work just fine (without the need for `eq(0)`). Or if it returns multiple objects and you only need the first you can use `siblings('.vote_num')[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
    var $vote_num_obj  = $(this).parent().find('.vote_num');
    var new_vote_num   = parseInt($vote_num_obj.attr('votes'))+1;

    $vote_num_obj.attr('votes', new_vote_num);
    $vote_num_obj.html(new_vote_num);
});
```

Put this script inside `$('document').ready(function(){  ..here..  });`

I suggest to change votes attribute of your span.vote_num to data-votes and change also the jquery attribute selector, this way it will be standard compliant.